# Find product tags by prefix and show them together in one text line on shopify frontend

Tags: jquery, shopify, liquid

Some of my products have tags with the same prefix for example:

`Color Family:Neutrals` and `Color Family:Beiges`.

I want that on the frontend, it would look like this:

`Color Family: Beiges, Neutrals`.

I successfully managed to get this line except, that it's repeated as many times as there are tags with the same prefix(in this case two times):

[image]

My liquid code:

```
{% for tag in product.tags %}
     {% if tag contains "Color Family:" %}
         <div class="bullet">
             <div class="left">Color Family:</div>
             <div class="right bold colorfamily-hook" style="font-weight: bold;">{{tag | replace: 'Color Family:', '' | replace: "||", ", "}}, </div>
        </div>
     {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var comma_replace = function (el) {
        return $(el).text().split(',').filter(function(word) {
            return word !== ' ' 
        }).join(',')
     } 

     $($('.colorfamily-hook')).text(comma_replace($('.colorfamily-hook'))) 
})
```

What should I change that the text line wouldn't be repeated if there is more than one tag with the same prefix ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Javascript, this can be achieved using Liquid:

```
{% assign k = 0 %}
{% for tag in product.tags %}
     {% if tag contains "Color Family:" %}
       {% if k == 0 %}
         {{ tag }}
       {% else %}
         {{ tag | remove: 'Color Family:' | prepend: ', ' }} 
       {% endif %}
       {% assign k = k | plus:1 %}
     {% else %}
       {% continue %}
     {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Explanation: first, you initiate a custom counter of your tag case. Then, if the tag is the first, you display it like it is. If it is not, you remove the first part and replace it by comma. Once this case check is done you iterate your custom counter.